# How can I manually pick line breaks, and let CSS make the containing div wide enough to hold them all?

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a box that I can float left containing a figure with a caption.  I want to flow the caption text around the image, and I would like to pick the line breaks explicitly - the length of the longest line should determine the width of the box.

The following *almost* works, except the line containing "AReallyLongWordIsHere" - instead of appearing directly under the previous line, to the right of the image - is appearing below the image.  I believe this happens because the width of the img - plus the width of the *first* line - determines the width of the box, and subsequent lines are broken accordingly.  Is there a way to specify that the box should be as long as the longest line?

```
<div id="a">
  <img src="blah"></img>
  Line one<br/>
  AReallyLongWordIsHere<br/>
  Another line<br/>
</div>

#a {
  float: left;
}

#a img {
  float:  left;
}
```

Comment: @NenadVracar That's interesting - that indeed seems to make the paragraph expand to the width of the longest line, but without taking into account the width of the float, so I get extra line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap text in `p` tag and use  `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`

```css
#a {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#a img, #a p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <p>Line one <br>
  AReallyLongWordIsHere <br>
  Another line <br></p>
</div>
```

Or you can just use `display: inline-flex:`

```css
#a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  Line one <br>
  AReallyLongWordIsHere <br>
  Another line <br>
</div>
```

Comment: That indeed makes the paragraph stretch to fit the text.  Now the left edge of each line is aligned with the right of the image, even those lines that fall below the image.  How can I get those to flow to the left again?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking, can you make a picture? Do you want just first line to be inline with image and others below the image?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way possible. It isn't responsive, that's for sure.

I've made a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7fbjp8k/3/) that demonstrates the effect. Although it works, you do have to know how high and wide the image is gonna be. You could use JavaScript to generate the CSS, though.

The HTML:

```
<div id="a">
    <img src="blah" alt="blah" />
    <span>Line one</span><br />
    <span>AReallyLongWordIsHere</span><br />
    <span>Another line</span><br />
    <span>Another line</span><br />
    <span>Back to start</span>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#a{
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

#a img{
    width: 5.5em;
    height: 5.5em;
    margin-right: -5.5em;
    float: left;
}

#a span{
    margin-left: 5.5em;
}

#a span:nth-of-type(n+5){
    margin-left: 0;
}
```